# Apache Spark not reading UTC timestamp from MongoDB correctly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, mongodb-atlas, timestamp-with-timezone

I've data stored in MongoDB collection and the timestamp column is not being read by Apache Spark correctly.
I'm running Apache Spark on GCP Dataproc.

Here is sample data :

```
In Mongo :

timeslot_date  : 
timeslot  |timeslot_date         |
+--------------------------+------
1683527400|{2023-05-08T06:30:00Z}|


When I use pyspark to read this (selected only specific columns :

+----------+-------------------+
timeslot  |timeslot_date      |
+----------+-------------------+
1683527400|2023-05-07 23:30:00|
+----------------+-------+-----
```

My understanding is, data in Mongo is in UTC format i.e. 2023-05-08T06:30:00Z is in UTC format.
I'm in PST timezone. I'm not clear why spark is reading it a different timezone format (neither PST nor UTC)
Note - it is not reading it as PST timezone, if it was doing that it would advance the time by 7 hours, instead it is doing the opposite.

Where is the default timezone format taken from, when Spark is reading data from MongoDB ?

Any ideas on this ?

tia!

Comment: Your time zone is PDT, not PST. The returned time is 23:30:00 PDT which is 06:30:00 GMT.